# How to convert datetime from SQL to UTC time in C#?

Tags: .net, datetime, utc

The date is stored as `datetime` data type in the SQL database. After reading this date through ADO.NET, how can I convert the `DateTime` that I received to UTC time? My local time is US EST.

For example 1:30 PM in EST (stored in the SQL database) has to be 6:30 PM in UTC.

Comment: How would you know the TimeZone of the stored `DateTime` in SQL Server ? it could be from multiple time zones. Use `DateTimeOffset` in SQL Server

Comment: I can't use ```DateTimeOffset``` in the SQL server. However I know that the local time is US EST.

Comment: so all the records have the same timezone ?

Comment: In the database, it is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the records are based on the EST time zone then you can do:

```
DateTime dtFromSqlServer = new DateTime(2017,03,28); //GET field from DB
TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var output = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dtFromSqlServer, tzInfo);
```

Comment: Does ```DateTime.ToUniversalTime()``` do the same?

Comment: @wonderfulworld, no... `The ToUniversalTime method converts a DateTime value from local time to UTC. To convert the time in a non-local time zone to UTC, use the TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo) method.`

Comment: @wonderfulworld, so if the current machine has EST has time zone, then `ToUniversalTime` and above code will return the same, but if the machine has different timezone then you will get different results.

Comment: So the ```ToUniversalTime``` looks at the Operating System time? Our Web API and the DB are in a server which has the EST time.

Comment: @wonderfulworld, I wouldn't use `ToUniversalTime`, There is an added dependency on the machine locale. Machine locale can change for a number of reason, and in that case you will end up re-writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) in the past.

```
DateTime dateEst = new DateTime(2017, 03, 28, 1, 30, 0); // This is where you'd pulled the DateTime value from your database.
DateTime dateUtc = dateEst.ToUniversalTime();
```

In contrast you can use [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) to get back to your original value.

Do take note these take in account of DST which is now, which is why this gives me 5:30, and not 6:30...